# Como renombro un archivo en tmp linux?

Tags: linux, línea-de-comandos, programacion-asincrona, subida-de-archivos

Como puedo verificar si un archivo esta en la carpeta temporal `tmp` y como hago para renombrar ese archivo a `hello_school`

Comment: Desde la línea de comandos puedes usar la instrucción **ls** o bien **find**. Encontrarás su documentación [aqui](http://es.tldp.org/Paginas-manual/man-pages-es-1.28/man1/ls.1.html) para `ls` y [aqui](http://es.tldp.org/Paginas-manual/man-pages-es-extra-0.8a/man1/find.1.html) para `find`.  Para renombrar usa `mv` mirando su [documentación](http://es.tldp.org/Paginas-manual/man-pages-es-1.28/man1/mv.1.html) tambien

Comment: Intentaste mv? mv numbreArchivo hello_school

Comment: @masterguru pon eso como respuesta, por favor.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro hecho. No he querido profundizar en la respuesta porque prefiero dar la caña que el pescado cuando las preguntas no demuestran demasiada investigación.

Answer (score 1):

Para buscar o localizar un archivo desde la línea de comandos puedes usar la instrucción **ls** o bien **find**. Encontrarás su documentación [aqui](http://es.tldp.org/Paginas-manual/man-pages-es-1.28/man1/ls.1.html) para `ls` y [aqui](http://es.tldp.org/Paginas-manual/man-pages-es-extra-0.8a/man1/find.1.html) para `find`.

Para renombrar usa `mv` mirando su [documentación](http://es.tldp.org/Paginas-manual/man-pages-es-1.28/man1/mv.1.html) también.